# Qt, CMake, and Ninja: ninja's segmentation fault

Tags: qt, cmake, ninja

Ninja's problem is stated as follows:

```
Qt CMake Error: Running '/home/klaus/Qt/Tools/Ninja/ninja' '-C' '/home/klaus/Projects/build-sermonfiller-Desktop_Qt_5_15_2_GCC_64bit-Debug' '-t' 'recompact' 
failed with: 

Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What did not work:**

- Reinstalling Ninja, reinstalling Qt
- Trying to update Ubuntu (currently it's 21.10 struggling to update to 22.04 LTS). There are some suggestions on the internet that updates may cause this problem.
- Updating Linux' dependencies
- Seeking to delete .ninja_deps, etc.

**What worked:**

- Deleting the build folder entirely.

In fact, CMake was unable to make my *make* files because of ninja's segfault.

Also, it's worth noting that my project worked on another computer with MacOs. Also, another project was built successfully. Thence, it was some problem with the build itself.